# index and match to external file

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to create a function that preforms an index and match (vlookup) to another file.  I have a file that is zipcodes in ColA with a relative cost factors in ColB.  I often find myself copying and pasting that sheet into my workbooks and doing a vlookup.  is there a way that i can create a "Function" where the only argument is the zipcode and it returns the cost factor for that zipcode without having to copy and re-write an index match function every time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) can reference a closed workbook.

Open both workbooks and build your first VLOOKUP or [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, '[extzips.xlsb]Sheet1'!$A:$B, 2, FALSE)
=INDEX([extzips.xlsb]Sheet1!$A:$A, MATCH(B2, [extzips.xlsb]Sheet1!$B:$B, 0))
```

Close the workbook with the zip references. The formula(s) will adjust to something like,

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, 'C:\Users\user\Documents\[extzips.xlsb]Sheet1'!$A:$B, 2, FALSE)
=INDEX('C:\Users\user\Documents\[extzips.xlsb]Sheet1'!$A:$A, MATCH(B2, 'C:\Users\user\Documents\[extzips.xlsb]Sheet1'!$B:$B, 0))
```

Those formulas can be copied or filled to new locations and will return the appropriate values.

Comment: thank you jeeped! the problem is that I a use this across many workbooks, not just work sheets.  Is there a way to save this as a "formula" so that i can just write "=geoscore(B2)" where geoscore is a function that we have defined to do the above look up. im just looking for a cleaner version of what you described. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, there are a couple of ways but any of these is going to involve at least as much work getting it into *'many workbooks'* with the possible exception of putting it into a personal macro workbook.